# dynamically add top in css?

Tags: css, less

Is there a way to dynamically add top in css/less? I have the following structure:

```
.a2a-desktop-right {
    right: 0px;

    .a2a_svg {
        position: absolute;
        right: 8px;
    }
}
```

`.a2a_svg` has some animation effects on hover and needs to be absolutely positioned, however there can be n-types of this element. Each one needs a top of 40px more than the previous. Any way to accomplish this without js?

**EDIT**

I can't define the style inline - it's a 3rd party script that generates these elements. That's also why javascript is out of the question - I won't know when the elements are rendered, and if I did it would still take time for the new styles to be applied.

Comment: i think you should use javascript and define your style inline.
for nested classes you can define different style in your css and just switch classes with javascript

Comment: @Alireza unfortunately I can't define the style inline - it's a 3rd party script that generates these elements. That's also why javascript is out of the question - I won't know when the elements are rendered, and if I did it would still take time for the new styles to be applied.

Comment: @Alireza Found a solution - less allows loops with mixins

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a way to do it with `less` after seeing the below by [edwinnwebb](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/edwinwebb/5155504/raw/eefc45f82efd259da0c8ce6bd7d26a44a9622f02/gistfile1.css).

```
/* Define two variables as the loop limits */
@from : 0;
@to : 10;

/* Create a Parametric mixin and add a guard operation */
.loop(@index) when(@index =< @to) {

/* As the mixin is called CSS is outputted */
div:nth-child(@{index}) {
    top: unit(@index * 100, px);
}

/* Interation call and operation */
.loop(@index + 1);
}

/* the mixin is called, css outputted and iterations called */
.loop(@from);

/*

## Output

div:nth-child(0) {
    top: 0px;
}
div:nth-child(1) {
    top: 100px;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
    top: 200px;
}
div:nth-child(3) {
    top: 300px;
}
div:nth-child(4) {
    top: 400px;
}
div:nth-child(5) {
    top: 500px;
}
div:nth-child(6) {
    top: 600px;
}
div:nth-child(7) {
    top: 700px;
}
div:nth-child(8) {
    top: 800px;
}
div:nth-child(9) {
    top: 900px;
}
div:nth-child(10) {
    top: 1000px;
}

*/
```

Applied to my problem becomes...

```
@iterations: 0;

.svg-loop (@iterations) when (@iterations =< 5) {
    .a2a-button.a2a-desktop-right:nth-of-type(@{iterations}) {
        .a2a_svg{
            top: unit((@iterations * 40) - 33, px);
        }
    }

    .svg-loop(@iterations + 1);
}
```